# PyQt QTableWidget редактирование

Tags: python, sqlite3, pyqt4

На форме имеется QTableWidget, я установил флаги на редактирование ячейки, но я не соображу как перехватить сигнал о редактировании, то есть что бы после редактирования и нажатия, скажем Enter, данные записались в БД. Использую Sqlite3.

флаги:

```
item1=QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(query.value(1))
        item1.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алгоритм прост:

1. п**И**шите функцию-слот, который будет выполнять нужное вам действие
2. цепляете к нему посредством механизма "[Signals & Slots](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html)" нужный [сигнал от QTableWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QTableWidget.html#signals)

Документация **Qt** очень хороша, не стоит ей пренебрегать. И пусть вас не смущают примеры на **C++** - вникайте в концепции. Всегда можно подсмотреть реализацию чего-либо в примерах, идущих в комплекте к **PyQt** - там их немало. Не грех еще заглянуть иной раз в примеры к [PySide/Examples](https://github.com/PySide/ExamplesSide/Examples). **PySide** это тоже бинд Qt к питону, но выпускаемый под более свободной лицензией и разрабатываемый самим Qt Project.